# Starting/Stopping docker's container from angular app

Tags: angular, typescript, docker

I'm creating a micro-services based application and from an angular front-end i'm able to list all my micro-services, I added buttons to stop/start/restart each of them via docker rest API.

Here is my docker service class from angular app :

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject  } from 'rxjs';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token'
  })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DockerService {


  private docker_api: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.docker_api = "http://10.1.10.202:5555/containers"
   }

   getContainerStatus(name: string) {
      return this.http.get(`${this.docker_api}/json?all=True&filters={"name":["${name}"]}` , httpOptions);
   }

   stopContainer(name: string) {
    this.http.post(`${this.docker_api}/${name}/stop`, {}, httpOptions);
   }

   startContainer(name: string) {
    this.http.post(`${this.docker_api}/${name}/start`, {}, httpOptions);
   }

   restartContainer(name: string) {
    this.http.post(`${this.docker_api}/${name}/restart`, {}, httpOptions);
   }


}
```

And I'm accessing it from setting.component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApplicationModel } from '../../application.model'
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router'
import { ApiService } from '../../api-service.service'
import { DockerService } from '../../docker.service'
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'


@Component({
  selector: 'app-settings',
  templateUrl: './settings.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./settings.component.scss']
})
export class SettingsComponent implements OnInit {

  app: ApplicationModel;
  apps : ApplicationModel[];
  container;
  map = new Map<string, string>();

  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute, private _apiService: ApiService, private _dockerService: DockerService) { 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    let id = +this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this._apiService.getApplications()
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.apps = data;
      console.log(data)
      for (let i = 0; i < this.apps.length; i++){
        if(this.apps[i].id == id){
          this.app = this.apps[i];
          console.log(this.app);
            this.app.microservices.forEach(ms => {
              console.log(ms);
                this._dockerService.getContainerStatus(ms.name).subscribe(data => {
              ms.state = data[0].State;
              console.log(data);
                });
            });
          console.log(this.app);
        }
      }
    });

  }

  back() {
    this.router.navigate(['/applications']);
  }

  start(name: string){
   this._dockerService.startContainer(name);
   console.log('started');
  }

  stop(name: string){
    this._dockerService.stopContainer(name);
     console.log('stopped');
  }

  restart(name: string){
   this._dockerService.restartContainer(name);
   console.log('restarted');
  }

}
```

start/stop/restart functions are called inside my html template with (click) :

```
<div class="row h-100">  
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 text-center my-auto">
        <div *ngIf="app" class="card shadow text-center  mx-auto justify-content-center">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h1>{{app.name | uppercase}}</h1>
              </div>
              <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="col">Micro Service</th>
                      <th scope="col">Status</th>
                      <th scope="col">Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                <tbody>
                  <tr *ngFor="let ms of app.microservices">
                    <td style="width: 33%">{{ms.name}}</td>
                    <td style="width: 33%">
                        <div *ngIf="ms.state === 'running'; else elseBlock">
                {{ms.state}}
                        </div>
                        <ng-template #elseBlock>{{ms.state}}</ng-template>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 33%">
                        <a (click)="start(ms.name)"><img src="../../../assets/img/start.png" height="50px" width="50px" class="settings mx-auto" appSelector></a>
                              <a (click)="stop(ms.name)"><img src="../../../assets/img/stop.png" height="50px" width="50px" class="settings mx-auto" appSelector></a>
                        <a (click)="restart(ms.name)"><img src="../../../assets/img/restart.png" height="50px" width="50px" class="settings mx-auto" appSelector></a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" class="text-center"><a (click)="back()"><img src="../../../assets/img/back.png" height="50px" width="50px" class="settings mx-auto" appSelector></a></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But here is the problem, nothing happens, the console.log works but no API call, nothing inside network tab but the request works with postman.

Btw, the getContainerStatus from docker.service that is called inside NgOnInit works fine.

Can someone help me ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not subscribing to your docker service http observables when you call them, so you never make the ajax call.

```
start(name: string){
       this._dockerService.startContainer(name).subscribe();
       console.log('started');
}
```

You might want to do something when the subscription completes, like trigger a notification:

```
start(name: string){
       this._dockerService.startContainer(name).subscribe(() => /* do something nice */);
       console.log('started');
 }
```

You can also tap your console log:

```
start(name: string){
       this._dockerService.startContainer(name)
            .pipe(
                tap(() => console.log('started'))
            )
            .subscribe(() => /* do something nice */);
 }
```